# /usr/bin/env: 'ruby': No such file or directory userdata in codedeploy ubuntu

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, ubuntu-14.04, aws-code-deploy

I've tried to install `CodeDeploy Agent` inside UserData in Ubuntu 14.04 with Cloudformation as follow:

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ruby
sudo apt-get install wget
cd /home/ubuntu
wget https://aws-codedeploy-eu-central-1.s3.amazonaws.com/latest/install
sudo chmod +x ./install
sudo ./install auto
sudo service codedeploy-agent start
```

After Cloudformation successfully and when I've `CodeDeploy Agent` in Terminal, found following message:

```
ubuntu@ip-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx:~$ sudo service codedeploy-agent status
● codedeploy-agent.service
   Loaded: not-found (Reason: No such file or directory)
   Active: inactive (dead)
```

So, I've tried to install manually starting from

```
ubuntu@ip-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx:~$ sudo ./install auto
/usr/bin/env: 'ruby': No such file or directory
```

Found that one. **But when I've installed manually those scripts inside user data, it was working perfectly. Please let me know which one is missing.**

Comment: hey, did you managed to solve this? I have the same error

Comment: @Madeo try with that link, https://www.reddit.com/r/aws/comments/7x5omp/automating_install_of_new_ssmcw_agents/

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the basic Amazon Linux image does not come with Ruby installed.

The solution that worked for me was to manually download and install Ruby on my EC2 instance using the package manager for your Linux distribution, such as yum

For this run:
`sudo yum install -y ruby`

After running the above command, you will see all the Ruby installation process prompts.
Once it finishes you can go ahead and continue to install Codedeploy, run:

```
wget https://aws-codedeploy-us-west-2.s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/latest/install

chmod +x ./install

sudo ./install auto
```

You should see the Codedeploy download and installation prompts.

That's it, now confirm Codeploy is working by running

```
sudo service codedeploy-agent status
```

Answer (score -1):

The error message is telling you that there is no command named `ruby` in the `$PATH`.

In 90% of all cases, when a computer tells you it cannot find something, the reason is that the something isn't there. (Computers are really good at finding things, they don't make random mistakes.) In this case, this would mean: there is no command named `ruby`.

In 90% of the rest of the cases, you are telling the computer to search the wrong places. In this case, this would mean: `ruby` is in a directory that is not on the `$PATH`.

Those are the most common ones.

Specifically for executables, there is also the possibility that the binary is not executable. And for shell scripts, there might be some characters that are interpreted as part of the file name. For example, a very popular one is having Windows line breaks in a shell script, where the OS will interpret everything up to the first `\n` as the shebang line and thus include the `\r` as part of the filename to execute.

Comment: I don't think so. When I've tried to install those scripts in EC2 UserData box, encounter same error.